# Google Play Service Testing

Tags: testing, google-play-services

I've got a question,
I want to test my app with Play Services, do I have to promote my apk from Alpha to Production?

It currently crashes everytime it tries to connect to the play services.

Comment: You can test before publish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope you don't even have to have it in alpha testing - you just have to make sure you have a game services linked to your app. You actually don't even need to upload an apk or anything for it to work [image]

https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling